# API Gateway mapping template converts JSON string to comma-separated key=value pairs

Tags: amazon-web-services, api-gateway

Mapping template noob here.

Using this query string as input:

userid=foo&firstname=bar&lastname=bat

I need to POST data to Kinesis as JSON, thus:

```
{  
    "userid":"foo",
    "firstname":"bar",
    "lastname":"bat"
}
```

However, according to a consuming Lambda, it arrives at Kinesis translated into comma-separated key=value pairs, thus:

userid=foo, firstname=bar, lastname=bat

Google found some old forum posts outlining the same problem, but no solution.

This is the mapping template I'm using:

```
{
    #set($data = {
        "userid":"$input.params('userid')",
        "firstname":"$input.params('firstname')",
        "lastname":"$input.params('lastname')"
    })
    "StreamName": "xyz",
    "Data": "$util.base64Encode($data)",
    "PartitionKey": "0"
}
```

It seems the mapping template is converting the $data dict into a comma-separated list of key=value pairs. Perhaps I should construct a JSON string rather than a dict, but, this behavior must be configurable, I'd think. How to instruct the system to construct JSON rather than KV?

Answer (score 3):

This wasn't exactly what I was looking for, but, I'm able to prevent the conversion to KV by constructing a string rather than a dict, as so:

```
{
    #set($data = "{
        ""userid"":""$input.params('userid')"",
        ""firstname"":""$input.params('firstname')"",
        ""lastname"":""$input.params('lastname')""
    }")
    "StreamName": "xyz",
    "Data": "$util.base64Encode($data)",
    "PartitionKey": "0"
}
```

I'm gonna leave this here since I did have to wrestle with it for a bit. Hopefully when Google sends someone here in future it'll be helpful.

Comment: Your answer gave a hint about how to convert the body of my request from json object into a string. I just set "body" : "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.body)" on my template, and worked like a charm, thanks.